# Transforming specific field of the RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to spark.I have a doubt in transforming the specific field of a RDD.
I have a file like below:

```
2016-11-10T07:01:37|AAA|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044|288364|2|3
2016-11-10T07:01:37|BBB|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044/BBB-1|304660|0|0
2016-11-10T07:01:37|TSB|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044/BBB-1/TSB-1|332164|NA|NA
2016-11-10T07:01:37|RX|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044/BBB-1/TSB-1/RX-1|357181|0|1
```

And I want ouput like below:In the third field I want to remove all characters and integers separated by |.

```
2016-11-10T07:01:37|AAA|16.12|329044|288364|2|3
2016-11-10T07:01:37|BBB|16.12|329044|1|304660|0|0
2016-11-10T07:01:37|TSB|16.12|329044|1|1|332164|NA|NA
2016-11-10T07:01:37|RX|16.12|329044|1|1|1|357181|0|1
```

how can I do that.
I tried the below code.

```
val inputRdd =sc.textFile("file:///home/arun/Desktop/inputcsv.txt");
val result =inputRdd.flatMap(line=>line.split("\\|")).collect;
def ghi(arr:Array[String]):Array[String]=
{
 var outlist=scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String]();
 for( i <-0 to arr.length-1){
if(arr(i).matches("(.*)-(.*)")){
var io=arr(i);  var arru=scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String](); 
if(io.contains("/"))
{
var ki=io.split("/");
for(st <-0 to ki.length-1 )
{
 var ion =ki(st).split("-");
 arru+=ion(1);
}  
var strui="";
for(in <-0 to arru.length-1)
{
strui=strui+arru(in)+"|";
}
outlist+=strui;
}
else
{           
var ion =arr(i).split("-");
outlist+=ion(1)+"|";
}
}
else
{
outlist+=arr(i);
}
}   
return outlist.toArray;
}
var output=ghi(result);
val finalrdd=sc.parallelize(out, 1);
finalrdd.collect().foreach(println);
```

Please help me.

Comment: What's your doubt? Something not working? What have you tried so far?

Comment: if you take the third field eg(MN-MN/AAA-329044/BBB-1) this field I want to convert to 329044|1.I want to remove all characters.

Comment: add the code which you have tried.

Comment: 2nd field eg(S16.12).I want to remove S.I want the plan 16.12

Comment: val inputRdd =sc.textFile("file:///home/arun/Desktop/inputcsv.txt");
val result =inputRdd.flatMap(line=>line.split("\\|")).collect;
var output=ghi(result);

Comment: i have written ghi function which will transform 3rd field .

Comment: code is length which i can't copy here

Comment: But I am not getting exact output.Is there any way how can i get the desired ouput as i explained

Comment: @Khumar you can edit the question and add the code.

Comment: Without seeing the current code it's not possible to tell you why your approach does not work and how it can be corrected.

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41197217/edit) your post and add the code - don't use comments to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

What we need to do is to extract the numbers from that field and add them as new entries to the `Array` being processed.

Something like this should do:

```
// use data provided as sample 
val dataSample ="""2016-11-10T07:01:37|AAA|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044|288364|2|3
2016-11-10T07:01:37|BBB|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044/BBB-1|304660|0|0
2016-11-10T07:01:37|TSB|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044/BBB-1/TSB-1|332164|NA|NA
2016-11-10T07:01:37|RX|S16.12|MN-MN/AAA-329044/BBB-1/TSB-1/RX-1|357181|0|1""".split('\n')

val data = sparkContext.parallelize(dataSample)

val records= data.map(line=> line.split("\\|"))

// this regex can find and extract the contiguous digits in a mixed string.
val numberExtractor = "\\d+".r.unanchored

// we replace field#3 with the results of the regex
val field3Exploded = records.map{arr => arr.take(3) ++ numberExtractor.findAllIn(arr.drop(3).head) ++ arr.drop(4)}

// Let's visualize the result
field3Exploded.collect.foreach(arr=> println(arr.mkString(",")))

2016-11-10T07:01:37,AAA,S16.12,329044,288364,2,3
2016-11-10T07:01:37,BBB,S16.12,329044,1,304660,0,0
2016-11-10T07:01:37,TSB,S16.12,329044,1,1,332164,NA,NA
2016-11-10T07:01:37,RX,S16.12,329044,1,1,1,357181,0,1
```

Comment: see it also as a Spark Notebook: https://gist.github.com/maasg/28109dc3ce14b894bde3dab40a42ab4b

Comment: How to store this result into RDD so that I can that use that RDD for some other transformations.

Comment: @khumar you can apply further transformations on this intermediate result or use one of the save As... functions. Check out the docs: http://spark.apache.org/documentation.html

Comment: What is wrong here.scala> val file5=field3Exploded.collect.foreach(arr=> arr.mkString(","))        scala> file5.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/cloudera/Aout1")
<console>:34: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Unit
              file5.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/cloudera/Aout1")

Comment: @khumar `collect` takes you out of RDD world. Check the types of your expression. Also, ask new questions instead of extending on comments.